# how to make ordered and unordered list in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

How to create simple ordered list in actionscript 3?
like

- aaaa
- bbbb
- cccc

I have to take the text from TextArea.

**UPDATE:**

```
    private function applyStyleEvent(event:Event):void
    {
        inputText = new TextLayoutFormat(inputTextArea.getFormatOfRange(null,startIndex,endIndex));

        if(event.currentTarget.id == "boldBttn")
        {
            inputText.fontWeight = (inputText.fontWeight == FontWeight.BOLD) ? FontWeight.NORMAL : FontWeight.BOLD;
        }   
        else if(event.currentTarget.id == "italicBttn" )
        {
            inputText.fontStyle = (inputText.fontStyle == FontPosture.ITALIC) ? FontPosture.NORMAL : FontPosture.ITALIC;
        }               
        else if(event.currentTarget.id == "underLineBttn" )
        {
            inputText.textDecoration =(inputText.textDecoration == TextDecoration.UNDERLINE)?TextDecoration.NONE : TextDecoration.UNDERLINE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you add the code you are using and have tried so far?

Comment: sorry..... I don't have any idea about that... But I did some formatting like bold, underline... see my update..... likewise I have to do that ordered list

Comment: How do you add the TextArea content? is it dynamic? fixed? the user should add something? has a pattern? Could you trace the inpurText.text?

Comment: TextArea is a fixed. I am having a separate mxml file for all components. It's somewhat big process.... but I can trace the value of TextArea.

Comment: I want to know just how to make ordered list using actionscript??? The input may be fixed or dynamic..... can you guide me  gPeart ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have an array with your content, you can try:

```
 var textArea = new TextArea();
 addChild(textArea);

 var list:Array = ["ccccc", "bbbbb", "aaaaa", "ddddd"]; 
 list.sort(Array.CASEINSENSITIVE); // default sort 
 trace(list); // output: aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc,ddddd 

 for(var i:int = 0, l:uint = list.length; i < l; i++)
 {
     textArea.appendText(list[i] + '\n');
 }
```

It's a way to sort your list, you can adapt to your code and make all necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this :
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4.html

**Edit :**

If you want to use bullets for TextField objects, you need to apply a bulleted TextFormat :

```
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
    var bulletTF:TextFormat = new TextFormat();   
    bulletTF.bullet = true;
    tf.setTextFormat(bulletTF);
```

If you need to use it inside your TextArea, use HTML :

```
var str:String = "<p>Here is your list :</p>";
for(var i:int = 0, i < yourList.length; i++)
{
     str += "<li>" + yourList[i] + "</li>";
}
myTextArea.htmlText += str;
```

Comment: Thank you Florian..... I just want to know another one.... If I am using **TextLayoutFormat**  class, can I make bullet for **TextArea** textflow?

Comment: Yes you can. Just add the following lines : 

`myTextArea.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString(str);`
`myTextArea.textFlow.format = myTextLayoutFormat;`